# Shiny input to set function in server

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on building a shiny app to show a non-homogeneous Poisson process.  I have 3 different lambda function to select from, and would like to display a plot of lambda over time.  My solution is to use a `selectInput` with the 3 functions as values.

#### ui.R

```
shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    title = "Non-Homogenious Poisson Process",
    tabPanel("Home",
             fluidPage(
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(

                   #select lambda function
                   selectInput("l_fun",
                               "Select Lambda Function:",
                               c("f(t) = |sin(t)|","f(t) = t","f(t) = log(t)")
                               )#end selectInput                       
                 ),#end sidebarPanel
                 mainPanel(
                   textOutput("test")
                 )#end mainPanel                   
               )#end sidebarLayout                
             )#end fluidPage                
    )#end tabPanel 'Home'        
  )#end navbarPage
)#end shinyUI
```

#### Server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  t_intervals <- 0:100

  l_calculation <- reactive({
    switch(input$l_fun,
           "f(t) = |sin(t)|" = function(t) abs(sin(t)),
           "f(t) = t" = function(t) t,
           "f(t) = log(t)" = function(t) log(t)
           )#end switch
  })#end l_

  y <- l_calculation(t_intervals)#calculate lambda

  output$test <- renderText({
    paste0(y,sep=",",collapse = ",")
  })
})
```

When I run the server outside of shiny, everything works.  But in shiny i get `Warning: Error in l_calculation: unused argument (t_intervals)`.

It's been a while since I've used shiny.  Also right now I'm just trying to display the lambda values, the plot is coming next.

Comment: Do you just want to print the value of `sin(t)`, `t`, `log(t)` based on user selection for now?

Comment: Yeah. So for `t=1:100` I want to get the 100 values for `sin(t)` or whatever function is selected.  I want to build this so I can easily add or remove functions in the future.

Comment: I am not sure if `function(t)` is required inside your `reactive` function. Can you try the following, and see if this is what you are expecting? `t_intervals <- 0:10
      
      l_calculation <- reactive({
        switch(input$l_fun,
               "f(t) = |sin(t)|" = abs(sin(t_intervals)),
               "f(t) = t" = t_intervals,
               "f(t) = log(t)" = log(t_intervals)
        )#end switch
      })#end l_
      
      output$test <- renderText({
        paste(l_calculation(), collapse = ", ")
      })`

Comment: @Sagar That works, but I'm going to be using this function multiple times across many sets of data so calculating values inside the switch isn't ideal.

Comment: Agreed. @Dean Attali answered with keeping the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried making the minimal changes to your code that would make it work. You do not call a reactive like a function, with arguments. Reactive variables can be accessed only by calling them without arguments. The "arguments" of reactive variables are reactive values (such as input values or other reactive variables), but there are implicit - you do not pass parameters into them.

Take a look at this code and hopefully it can help you understand it better.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "Non-Homogenious Poisson Process",
  tabPanel("Home",
           fluidPage(
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(

                 #select lambda function
                 selectInput("l_fun",
                             "Select Lambda Function:",
                             c("f(t) = |sin(t)|","f(t) = t","f(t) = log(t)")
                 )#end selectInput                       
               ),#end sidebarPanel
               mainPanel(
                 textOutput("test")
               )#end mainPanel                   
             )#end sidebarLayout                
           )#end fluidPage                
  )#end tabPanel 'Home'        
)#end navbarPage

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  t_intervals <- 0:100

  l_calculation <- reactive({
    switch(input$l_fun,
           "f(t) = |sin(t)|" = function(t) abs(sin(t)),
           "f(t) = t" = function(t) t,
           "f(t) = log(t)" = function(t) log(t)
    )#end switch
  })#end l_

  #calculate lambda
  y <- reactive({
    l_function <- l_calculation()
    l_function(t_intervals)
  })

  output$test <- renderText({
    paste0(y(),sep=",",collapse = ",")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew I was forgetting something important about shiny.